# Arrangements of Colors in Sequence

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

I'm asking for help with checking my work.

I need the set of possible arrangements of unknown colors across sequences of lengths 1 to 4. I've numbered the colors based on their order of introduction from left to right. Have I found all possible arrangements?

I've included the reasoning that lead to finding each arrangement.

````
Length 1
--------
1 - one color

Length 2
--------
11 - one color
12 - two colors

Length 3
--------
111 - one color
122 - two colors, first peg different
121 - two colors, second peg different
112 - two colors, third peg different
123 - three colors

Length 4
--------
1111 - one color
1222 - two colors, unequal counts, first peg different
1211 - two colors, unequal counts, second peg different
1121 - two colors, unequal counts, third peg different
1112 - two colors, unequal counts, fourth peg different
1122 - two colors, equal counts, second of first in first position
1212 - two colors, equal counts, second of first in second position
1221 - two colors, equal counts, second of first in third position
1123 - three colors, two of first color, second of first in first position
1213 - three colors, two of first color, second of first in second position
1231 - three colors, two of first color, second of first in third position
1223 - three colors, two of second color, second of second in first position
1232 - three colors, two of second color, second of second in second position
1233 - three colors, two of third color
1234 - four colors
```
````

Comment: [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) and [Bell Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

Comment: The punchline is that, yes, you did find all of the arrangements.  In the end however, in combinatorics we typically do not care to actually list everything out (*though understanding a method by which we could list them all out if we wished may be important*) and prefer to count in more efficient methods instead.  You should not try to list out all $B_6=203$ ways in which you could sequence your colors if we had six positions available.  The list would not be readable and would be too prone to mistakes.  It becomes far less readable when talking about tens or hundreds or more positions.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think it is important to encourage people asking combinatorics questions on MSE to list out all of the small arrangments. It helps ensure the problem is clearly communicated and shows effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have found all of the arrangements. I know this, because what you are counting are equivalent to equivalence relations on a set of size $n$, where $n$ is the length, and your counts match the [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number), which enumerate equivalence relations.

Each of your colorings induces an equivalence relation on $\{1,\dots,n\}$, where $i$ and $j$ are equivalent if and only if they have the same color. Conversely, given an equivalence relation on $\{1,\dots,n\}$, you get a coloring as follows. For everything in the equivalence class of $1$, color all of those positions with color $1$. Then, letting $x$ be the smallest uncolored position, label everything in the equivalence class of $x$ with the color $2$. Continue in this fashion until every position is assigned a color.